# How to specialize or overload global template function for all instances of template class?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

How can I specialize or overload function `func` so that specialization handles all instances of MyClass? Assume `func` is a librarian function (like `std::swap` for example) so I can't change `func`, and I can't replace or wrap it, I have to specialize it.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
};

template<typename T>
void func(const T&)
{
    std::cout << "Default" << std::endl;
}

// I don't want to copy this stuff for every instance of MyClass
template<>
void func<MyClass<int>>(const MyClass<int>&)
{
    std::cout << "Specialization" << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    func(int(0)); // "Default"

    func(MyClass<int>()); // "Specialization"

    func(MyClass<double>()); // "Default" but I want "Specialization" here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. That is solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few examples of what you can do.

```
template<typename T>
void func(const T&)
{
    std::cout << "Default" << std::endl;
}

template<template<typename> class A , typename B>
void func(const A<B>&)
{
    std::cout << "Overload All templated classes with one templated argument B" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void func(const MyClass<T>&)
{
    std::cout << "Overload Myclass with some templated argument T" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: These are not specializations. These are overloads. And you DO NOT need a 'default templated function' for this to work. Check http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm to understand the difference.

Comment: @Tomek, thanks for commentary. You're right. Initially I was willing to make specialization but Yochai has provided me with overloading sample which is what actually I've been looking for. Thank you both anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the global `func` in anyway and still want to avoid copying one way is to use macro to automate the repeatative stuff for you.

```
#define Specialize(TYPE) \
template<> \
void func<MyClass<TYPE>>(const MyClass<TYPE>&) \
{ \
    std::cout << "Specialization" << std::endl; \
}

Specialize(int);
Specialize(double);
```

If you have freedom to alter `MyClass<T>`, then place all the common functionality of `MyClass<T>` into a common non-template base class:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass<T> : public MyClassBase // <---- a common base class
...
```

And simply overload or specialize `func()` only for `MyClassBase`:

```
void func(const MyClassBase&)
{
    std::cout << "Specialization" << std::endl;
}
```